# What is the time complexity of writing a string to console?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

My coworker and I were discussing the time complexity of writing a string to console, and being unable to find an answer online I figured I'd ask here:

Say I have a string of length n.  Is writing that string to the console always an O(n) operation?  I assumed it would have to be at least O(n), but not being intimately familiar with how console output works I can't say for sure.

Comment: "at least O(n)" <- you should write Omega(n) for a lower bound. So the claim is: printing n characters is Θ(n) - a lower and upper bound.

Comment: @sdcwc - good point, Θ(n) is actually what I'm looking for

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In theory, yes, it's O(N). In reality, there's frequently enough overhead in initially getting access to the console that for almost any reasonable length of string (i.e., one that it makes sense to display on the console at all), it's nearly a constant.

Bottom line: big-O is about a limit as N approaches infinity -- but you should only ever write relatively small amounts of data to the console (and fairly slowly), so big-O is almost never relevant to this task.